# Refactoring int x, int y to Pair position (Java)

Tags: java, refactoring

I am writing a chess program in OOP design, and I am trying to refactor my code. The first challenge was to group all int x and int y combination into a Pair object (Pair position) that contains int x and int y information.

So my board class looked something like

```
public class Board {

    public static final int NUM_OF_ROWS = 8;
    public static final int NUM_OF_COLS = 8;

    int x, y;

    //Initialization of NUM_OF_ROW x NUM_OF_COLS size of 2d Piece array
    Piece[][] board = new Piece[NUM_OF_ROWS][NUM_OF_COLS];

    public Piece getPiece(int x, int y) {

        return board[x][y];

    }
   ....
```

originally.

And I tried to change

```
int x, y;
```

to look like

```
int x, y;
Point position = new Point(x, y)
```

And all methods to have a new parameter

```
public Piece getPiece(int x, int y) to public Piece getPiece(Point pos)

public void placePiece(int x, int y, Piece pieceToPlace) to public void placePiece(Point pos, Piece pieceToPlace)
```

But the problem that I had was in the testing.

One of my test cases looked like

```
public void correctMovementTest() {
    Knight n1 = new Knight(Player.UP);
    board.placePiece(4, 3, n1);
    board.movePiceTo(2, 2, n1);
    assertEquals(board.getPiece(4, 3), null);
    assertEquals(board.getPiece(2, 2), n1);
}
```

when I just used the int x int y parameter. Basically placing the piece to x = 4 and y = 3 and moving it to x = 2 and y = 2 and checking if it has moved correctly.

But now when I try to change this to look like

```
public void correctMovementTest() {
    Knight n1 = new Knight(Player.UP);
    board.placePiece((4, 3), n1); // changed
    board.movePiceTo((2, 2), n1); //changed
    assertEquals(board.getPiece((4, 3)), null); // changed
    assertEquals(board.getPiece((2, 2)), n1); // changed
}
```

it gives me an error saying "the left-hand side of the argument must be a variable" which I don't really understand.

I am assuming making a new Point object like

```
Point pos = new Point(4,3);
```

would work, but this just makes the code dirtier and isn't refactoring.

Can someone please correct my approach?

Comment: Why would you think that putting parenthesis around the two numbers would magically make it a `Point` object? Try `board.placePiece(new Point(4, 3), n1)` instead.

Comment: Is that how it's supposed to be used? Would there be a better way to make it more simple? Putting new Point for all test cases would be considered even more complicated.

Comment: Yes, that's how `Point` is supposed to be used. --- Define "more simple". The original code was simple to call, so why is that not the answer?

Comment: I just wanted to decrease the number of parameters that functions use so that it can look neater. Wouldn't changing public Piece getPiece(int x, int y) to public Piece getPiece(Point pos) be considered as refactoring?

Comment: Yes, what you are doing is "refactoring", you're taking the existing code and changing it.  Is this a good thing or a bad thing? That's a broad question and not one that's suited for SO (maybe code review, but you'd have to read to the terms) - Having said that, it's typically easier to express your idea using `Point` (move piece to point, check board cell at point, etc), then with individual x/y parameters.  You could also create a `enum` which described the board (`A1`, `A2`, etc) and use that instead, which would perform two actions, one - validation and two simplification

Comment: It is not dirtier, the code remains easy to understand. Granted, it is more verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you are doing is "refactoring", you're taking the existing code and changing it.

It's typically easier to express your idea using `Point` (move piece to point, check board cell at point, etc), then with individual x/y parameters.

> but this just makes the code dirtier...

You could create a `enum` which described the board (`A1`, `A2`, etc) and use that instead, which would perform two actions, one - validation and two - simplification

For example

```
public enum Square {
    A1(new Point(0, 9)), 
    A2(new Point(0, 8)), 
    A3(new Point(0, 7)), 
    A4(new Point(0, 6)), 
    A5(new Point(0, 5)), 
    A6(new Point(0, 4)), 
    A7(new Point(0, 3)), 
    A8(new Point(0, 2)), 
    A9(new Point(0, 1)), 
    A10(new Point(0, 0));
    // ... The rest of the board        

    private Point point;

    private Square(Point point) {
        this.point = point;
    }

    public Point getPoint() {
        return point;
    }        
}
```

While this is an initially large setup, it makes the rest of the code much simpler...

```
movePieceTo(piece, Square.A3)
```

It's also self documenting :)

Because `Square` also maintains the information about the `Point` itself, you don't need to do further transformations

```
public void movePieceTo(Piece piece, Square square) {
    Point point = square.getPoint();
    //...
}
```

As a rough idea.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. So, do you think this is a better approach than just using int x and int y as a position?

Comment: @user6792790 That's a matter of opinion, both `x/y` and `Point` still need to be valid to make sure they are valid values (within the context of the board) - this provides a level self validation. It's much easier to read, `Square.A1` has more meaning then `0, 9` when reading the code. It also meets your requirement of cleaning up the code, as you don't need to create a secondary object when you want to call the methods - you could accomplish the same thing with `static Point ...`, but that's one of the reasons we got `enum`s :P